# Curl command works locally but fails with error 55 in Azure DevOps pipeline bash task

Tags: curl, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm facing an issue with a curl command that works successfully when executed locally but fails with error 55 when running in an Azure DevOps pipeline using a bash task.

This is the command that works locally:
`curl --no-keepalive -X POST -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -u user:pass -F "file=@output_final.xml" -F "info=@testExec.json" "https://***.***.****/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/robot/multipart"`

However, when I run this in Azure DevOps, I get the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" /d/a/_temp/9f68be43-cac3-4312-8c3f-1c12c97dd9da.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
 11  544k    0     0   11 65535      0   202k  0:00:02 --:--:--  0:00:02  203k
curl: (55) Failed sending data to the peer
```

I've already tried several troubleshooting steps, but I couldn't find a solution. What could be causing this issue in Azure DevOps, and how can I resolve it?

I've tried using the --no-keepalive option, but the error remains the same.

This is the yaml

```
    trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

strategy:
  matrix:
    RobotTestsWithPython3:
      python.version: '3.7'
  maxParallel: 1

steps:

- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs: 
    versionSpec: '$(python.version)'
    architecture: 'x64'

- script: pip install robotframework robotframework-pabot robotframework-seleniumlibrary webdrivermanager
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

- powershell: |
    Write-Host "Robot Framework tests"
    robot --nostatusrc -x 'mergedxunit.xml' -N "Zeitreel CommerceCloud Tests" -d '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\reports\' '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\ZeitReel-Automation\TestCases\ZippySmokeTests.robot'
  failOnStderr: true
  displayName: 'Run Robot Framework Tests'
  continueOnError: true

- powershell: |
    Write-Host "Rerun Failed tests"
    robot --nostatusrc --rerunfailed '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\reports\output.xml' -x 'mergedxunit2.xml' --output 'output2.xml' -N "Zeitreel CommerceCloud Tests" -d '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\reports\' '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\ZeitReel-Automation\TestCases\ZippySmokeTests.robot'
  failOnStderr: true
  displayName: 'Rerun Failed Robot Framework Tests'
  continueOnError: true

- powershell: |
    Write-Host "Run rebot to merge results"
    rebot --nostatusrc --merge --outputdir '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\reports' --output 'output_final.xml' --report 'merged_report.html' --log 'merged_log.html' '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\reports\output.xml' '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\reports\output2.xml'
  failOnStderr: true
  displayName: 'Merge Robot Framework Test Results'
  continueOnError: true

- powershell: |
    Write-Host "Run rebot to merge results xunit"
    rebot --nostatusrc --merge --xunit '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\reports\outputxunit_final.xml' '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\reports\output.xml' '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\reports\output2.xml'
  failOnStderr: true
  displayName: 'Merge Robot Framework Test Results (xUnit)'
  continueOnError: true

  
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    testResultsFiles: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\reports\outputxunit_final.xml'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Robot Results'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\reports\' # string. Required. Path to publish. Default: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory).
    ArtifactName: 'Robot_ResultsOutput' 
    publishLocation: 'Container' 

- bash: |
    curl --no-keepalive -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -u user:pass -F "file=@$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\reports\output_final.xml" -F "info=@testExec.json" "https://xxx.xxxx.xxx/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/robot/multipart"
  displayName: "Upload to OSF"
  continueOnError: true


schedules:
- cron: "0 5 * * 1-5"
  displayName: Nightly build
  branches:
    include:
    - main
- cron: "0 13 * * 1-5"
  displayName: Midday build
  branches:
    include:
    - main
```

Comment: Please add your pipeline YAML code. It's very easy to mess something up when there are line breaks involved.

Comment: I have the same issue :/